# Symfony2 and Doctrine2: relation on 2 fields between 4 tables

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm, relational-database

I have got 4 entities (Address, User, Contact, Account). Every record in User, Contact and Account can have many Addresses. What I have done is:

```
/**
 * Address
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="address")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Address
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="join_id", type="integer")
     */
    private $joinId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="join_type", type="string", length=16)
     */
    private $joinType;

    ........

}
```

So as join_type I am saving USER, CONTACT or ACCOUNT and as join_id I am saving the ID of related record in User, Contact and Account entity.

Is there a way to do this somehow using relations, so I don't need to run extra queries to get Address and it would be easier to saving this?

Answer (score 4):

I guess the Doctrine Single Table Inheritance (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance) is exactly what you need. So, you'll have one top-hierarchy entity - Address & 3 extending entities for each of your relation - UserAddress, ContactAddress, AccountAddress. Just define all common properties at Address entity, relations definitions move to inheriting entities.